# Mongo DB Replica Disk Writes

Tags: mongodb

Our secondary instances are reporting much higher disk write rate than the primary. Is this expected behavior in a replica set? Given that the oplog gets copied and replayed from the primary periodically, what's contributing to additional writes on secondaries?

Version: 3.4.1
StorageEngine: WiredTiger

Primary: i3.8xlarge
Secondaries: i3en.3xlarge

Comment: That's not expected behavior. What version of mongo are you on? How about storage engine (MMAPV1 vs. WiredTiger)? Any difference in configuration for primary vs. secondary?

Comment: Secondary nodes retrieve the oplog in batches, so you may see higher spikes in disk writes, but the overall average should be about the same.

Comment: Version: 3.4.1 StorageEngine: WiredTiger

Comment: Primary is running on i3.8xlarge instance and secondaries are on i3.8xlarge

Answer (score 0):

Update: 
1. The issue disappeared after a couple of days. 
2. Secondaries are showing disk writes comparable to  primary.

We are assuming there was a one-off issue that caused this behavior. In absence of enough historical data we chose to pause the investigation given that the problem has disappeared.